# ReactJS - How to avoid a specif image to be maximized in Lightbox Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this react component that uses the 'react-lightbox-component' dependency.

http://jfcaiceo.github.io/react-lightbox-component/

I want to prevent all images named as 'decorative_pic' from being maximized as lightbox

these images should remain as thumbnails and can not be maximized in Lightbox

The other images should be maximized in default behavior.

for example:

```
/*
    pic_01 -> should be maximized 
    pic_02 -> should be maximized 
    pic_03 -> should be maximized 
    decorative_pic -> forbidden to be maximized 
    decorative_pic -> forbidden to be maximized 
    decorative_pic -> forbidden to be maximized 
*/
```

Component React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';    

    const LightBoxTest = () => (

      <div>

        <Lightbox images={[
          {
            src: '../images/pic_01.jpg'       
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_03.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
          src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'  
          }
        ]} />
      </div>
    );

export default LightBoxTest
```

I succeeded in blocking these decorative images from being clicked using these css rules:

```
img[src*='decorative']{
  cursor:default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

But it solved only one part of the problem. Actually when you click on these images, the respective lightbox doesn't appear how should be in right way.

So the issue is when you click on the next button inside lightbox. These decorative images appear as maximized inside the lightbox and respecting the default way and I don't want it.

How to solve it? Maybe overwriting some dependency method? to avoid these decorative images to be inserted into the maximized lightbox groups? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library doesn't have available props to pass functions in order to disable the click event for certain images as you can see [here](https://github.com/jfcaiceo/react-lightbox-component/blob/74f578e8c53bcdcdcfc68bb7de0149a9f4a27fec/src/lib/components/Lightbox.jsx#L74). Neither you can control the events for next and previous pictures.

What you can do is to pass the `renderImagesFunc` prop to override the function that renders all images. This disables the `onClick` function but it doesn't disable the next and prev events.

```js
<Lightbox images={[
    { src: '../images/pic_01.jpg' },
    { src: '../images/pic_02.jpg' },
    { src: '../images/pic_03.jpg' },
    { src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg' },
    { src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg' },
    { src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg' }
  ]},
  renderImageFunc={(idx, image, toggleLightbox, width, height) => (
    <img
      key={idx}
      src={!!image.thumbnail ? image.thumbnail : image.src}
      className="lightbox-img-thumbnail"
      style={{ width: width, height: height }}
      alt={image.title}
      onClick={
        image.src.includes("decorative_pic") ? null : toggleLightbox.bind(null, idx)
      }
    />
  )}
/>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/72w17w5z0j

Another option is to use a library that already has more control functions as props, such as [react-images](https://github.com/jossmac/react-images)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your just need render a new decorative images before your component Lightbox.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';    

  const DecorativeImages = [
    "../images/decorative_pic.jpg",
    "../images/decorative_pic2.jpg",
    "../images/decorative_pic3.jpg"
  ]

    const LightBoxTest = () => (

      <div>

        <Lightbox images={[
          {
            src: '../images/pic_01.jpg'       
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_03.jpg'        
          },
        ]} />
        {DecorativeImages.map(img => (
          <dvi>
            <img src={img}/>
          </dvi>
        ))
        })}
      </div>
    );

export default LightBoxTest
```